# What's the easiest way to redirect to the previous page with PHP?

Tags: php, url, post, redirect, header

I'm using a form to submit some post information to a PHP script. After the script finishes, I want it to redirect right back to the page the user came from. Right now I'm just using header() with a static URL. I've found a ton of very conflicting information about this around the internet, so I'm wondering what StackOverflow thinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`HTTP_REFERER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Yep, that should work. And @Marc B, I'll just make sure I set an alternative static URL in case $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is blank. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

access the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable and redirect to this. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

the way i would do it is use a [session](http://w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp) variable to store the current page URL everytime it is accessed.

```
$_SESSION['last_url'] = <get current url>
```

replace your static url in the header with $_SESSION['last_url']. Depending on how you implement your PHP, you can use search google for "current url php" or just $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] (stackoverflow doesnt allow me to put more than 1 link!)

Answer (score 0):

Use REQUEST_URI But watch out for that presiding slash/