# Reliability way for understand previous page address

Tags: php, url

I want that after opening some page, redirect browser on previous page. I know about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but this is not reliability right? There is better way for understand previous  page url ?

Comment: you want redirection ..why not trying header method ?

Comment: you can save the previous url in Session or put it in query string.. see this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282008/whats-the-easiest-way-to-redirect-to-the-previous-page-with-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will store the pages in a session.
Works a bit like if you do a recently viewed.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['pages'][] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];


if ( Count ( $_SESSION['pages'] ) > 2 ){
 Array_Shift ( $_SESSION['pages'] );
}  

if ( Count ( $_SESSION['pages'] ) > 2 ){
 foreach ($_SESSION['pages'] as $key => $link)
{
if ($_SESSION['pages'][$key] == '')
{
    unset($_SESSION['pages'][$key]);
}
} 
}

//this will output previous page                                
echo $_SESSION['pages'][0];
```

maybe a bit overkill, but you could keep a history of pages in an array for the past few